# How to assign results from 2 separate variables in a third variable?

Tags: javascript

Pretty trivial question here. Not able to figure out.
I am trying to get results from `primaryWork` and `secondaryWork` and assign those results to variable `myWorkList`. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong here.

Thanks

```
  let myWorkList
  let primaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === null)
  let secondaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === this.currentWorker.id)
  if (this.list) {
    if (this.superuser && this.currentWorker) myWorkList = primaryWork && secondaryWork
  }
  return myWorkList
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console window of a browser when trying to run this code?

Comment: This looks to me like a good question but poorly worded. Obviously a single variable can't have two values, which is what it sounds like you're asking. Try giving example input and expected output to clarify -- this would make it obvious that you're taking in an array and wish to create an array.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you need to check for undefined, null, etc. by doing `if(this.list)`, then you shouldn't be doing the previous two lines before this check is done.

Comment: `if (this.list) {}` this conditon is pointless. if `this.list` was falsy, `this.list.filter(...)` would have already thrown an Error. And if  `this.superuser && this.currentWorker` ain't true, then it is pointless to generate the lists in the first place. How about this: `return (this.list && this.superuser && this.currentWorker)? this.list.filter(r => r.worker === null || r.worker === this.currentWorker.id): undefined;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like both `primaryWork` and `secondaryWork` are arrays. You're probably looking for the [`.concat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
  let myWorkList
  let primaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === null)
  let secondaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === this.currentWorker.id)
  if (this.list) {
    if (this.superuser && this.currentWorker) myWorkList = primaryWork.concat(secondaryWork)
  }
  return myWorkList
```

Or, fixing some potential bugs in your code:

```
  // whoever is using the return value from this function expects an array, so if this.list is undefined (or if this.superuser is false) we should return an empty array instead of undefined
  let myWorkList = []
  // if this.list is undefined, this.list.filter will fail - so we do it inside the conditional block
  if (this.list) {
    let primaryWork = [];
    let secondaryWork = [];

    // if this.superuser or this.currentWorker are false, we don't need to waste CPU cycles computing this.list.filter()
    if (this.superuser)
      // I made the assumption (correct me if I'm wrong) that if r.worker is null, the work belongs to the superuser
      primaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === null)

    // if this.currentWorker is undefined, this.currentWorker.id will fail -- so we perform this filter inside yet another conditional block
    if (this.currentWorker)
      secondaryWork = this.list.filter(r => r.worker === this.currentWorker.id)

    myWorkList = primaryWork.concat(secondaryWork)
  }
  return myWorkList
```

Finally, you can string this all into a single `filter` and only iterate over the list once instead of twice, like so:

```
  return (
    // Check that this.list is defined before filtering
    this.list ?
      this.list.filter(r =>
        // superuser case
        (this.superuser && r.worker === null)
        || // or
        // non-superuser case
        (this.currentWorker && r.worker === this.currentWorker.id)
      )
    // Return an empty array if this.list was undefined
    : []
  );
```

Note that in this final version we don't instantiate `myWorkList`, `primaryWork`, ***or*** `secondaryWork`. We don't need to allocate empty arrays in memory just to garbage collect them later if we can directly return the final value we want. This final form should run 2-3 times faster:

- Twice as fast since we iterate the `this.list` array once instead of twice
- ***A little bit*** faster than that because we avoid unnecessary memory allocations

Preliminary benchmarks peg it at about 2.4 faster on my machine:

```
var list = [{worker: null}, {worker: null}, {worker: 1}, {worker: 2}, {worker: 2}, {worker: 3}, {worker: 4}, {worker: null}, {worker: 2}]

var d0 = new Date(); for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) { var primary = list.filter(r => r.worker === null); var secondary = list.filter(r => r.worker === 2); primary.concat(secondary); } console.log(new Date() - d0);
// 659

var d0 = new Date(); for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) { list.filter(r => r.worker === null || r.worker === 2); } console.log(new Date() - d0);
// 272
```

Comment: I believe your answer is good, but as I just said in the comments, I think you can improve your answer by moving the declaration of `primaryWork` and `secondaryWork` inside of the `if(this.list)` as if this check is necessary the variable declarations for `primaryWork` and `secondaryWork` could prove problematic.

Comment: @stevendesu thanks for the response. Yes i was looking for concat() here.
essentially `primaryWork` and `secondaryWork` both return array but i needed a way to combine those two.   
@RyanWilson I was able to use your suggestions to improve this method as well. Thanks